# Cannot get static files in python/flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, static, frontend

I am trying to serve static index.html in flask, along with some javascript code, but i am getting a 404 or

```
ValueError: Unable to infer MIME-type because no filename is available. Please set either `attachment_filename`, pass a filepath to `filename_or_fp` or set your own MIME-type via `mimetype`.
```

in debug console.

My code snippets that i think are of key importance are those:

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='/static')

@app.route('/' ,methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/static/<path:path>', methods=['GET'])
def staticReturn(path):
    return app.send_static_file(path)
```

i get index.html served to me, but no files that i refer to index.html. And i refer to my files as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: Shouldn't you start your href with a slash? href="/static/bootstrap.css"

Comment: Doesnt work with that either :(